# Regular expression matching literal comma literal comma literal.. pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I want to force the users to write data in a textBox that matches exact pattern. The data is for a database column which could be null so what I need is :

```
A,B,C,D,Z,E...Y
```

What must keep in mind - the filed is nullable so the first char could be literal or nothing. After the first char I may or may not have comma (depending on if there are more literals following) but if there is it mus be only one. After that I can accept multiple `Literal comma` insertion but the text mus finish again with literal. I guess all this is visible from the example pattern above but just wanted to make it clear.

Here is my attempt:

```
string RegExPattern = @"^[A-Z]?,?[A-Z],*[A-Z]"
```

which sadly doesn't work.

Comment: Why not use a `string.Split`? seems simpler and also I think faster to execute than a regular expression...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the first parameter, put the comma and the parameter together and apply the repeater to them. Don't forget the `$` to match the end of the string.

```
string RegExPattern = @"^[A-Z]?(,[A-Z])*$"
```

Comment: Perfect, this is as concise as it gets :-)

Comment: Oh, wait ... wouldn't this also match: ",A,B,C"?

Comment: Yes, it would - there, fixed it: `^([A-Z](,[A-Z])*)?$`

Comment: Thanks. Those regex are hard stuff.

Comment: @chris: Yes, it would match ",A,B,C". It wasn't a mistake, that's how I interpreted the question. Nice fix.